# Error in !is.na(v.e) && v.e > 0 when using lme4 for mixed-effects model in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I did not find anything similar to my issue.

I have single cell expression data from 20 different experiments (`29733genes x 24489 cells`). We want to see if there are differences in gene expression between levels in a factor `cell_types` (4 levels) by each level of another variable that has 3 levels (for discretion lets call it `factor2`).

The objective is to obtain differentially expressed genes when testing these contrasts:

```
contrast_matrix <- makeContrasts(
  "Cell_typeAvsOther_Factor2:level1" = Cell_typeA_Factor2_level1 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level1) / 3,
  "Cell_typeAvsOther_Factor2:level2" = Cell_typeA_Factor2_level2 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level2) / 3,
  "Cell_typeAvsOther_Factor2:level3" = Cell_typeA_Factor2_level3 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level3) / 3, 
  
  "Cell_typeBvsOther_Factor2:level1" = Cell_typeB_Factor2_level1 - (Cell_typeA_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level1) / 3,
  "Cell_typeBvsOther_Factor2:level2" = Cell_typeB_Factor2_level2 - (Cell_typeA_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level2) / 3,
  "Cell_typeBvsOther_Factor2:level3" = Cell_typeB_Factor2_level3 - (Cell_typeA_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level3) / 3, 
  
  "Cell_typeCvsOther_Factor2:level1" = Cell_typeC_Factor2_level1 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level1) / 3,
  "Cell_typeCvsOther_Factor2:level2" = Cell_typeC_Factor2_level2 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level2) / 3,
  "Cell_typeCvsOther_Factor2:level3" = Cell_typeC_Factor2_level3 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeD_Factor2_level3) / 3,
  
  "Cell_typeDvsOther_Factor2:level1" = Cell_typeD_Factor2_level1 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level1 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level1) / 3,
  "Cell_typeDvsOther_Factor2:level2" = Cell_typeD_Factor2_level2 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level2 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level2) / 3,
  "Cell_typeDvsOther_Factor2:level3" = Cell_typeD_Factor2_level3 - (Cell_typeB_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeA_Factor2_level3 + Cell_typeC_Factor2_level3) / 3, 
  levels = design_matrix
)
```

To simplify my model I combined cell type and factor2 into a unified factor.

Then we have batch factor. Here I show you the distribution of cell types across batches. As you can see some batches are celltype specific:

```
           celltypeA celltypeB celltypeC celltypeD
  batch_1          0         0       441         0
  batch_10         0        63         3        58
  batch_11       181        13         7        11
  batch_12         2        36         2      1144
  batch_13         0        16         2       876
  batch_14        58       265      3226       469
  batch_15        19        66       115       858
  batch_16         0        73       100      1996
  batch_17         0        29       783         1
  batch_18         2        89       192       884
  batch_19      1152       459        33        71
  batch_2        193         3         0         0
  batch_20         0      2219         2         2
  batch_3        198        63         0         0
  batch_4          8         3         3       208
  batch_5          8        12       499         2
  batch_6       1878       465         8         1
  batch_7       3642        72       293        46
  batch_8          0       206         0         1
  batch_9        602        52         2         3
```

Using a fix effects model with a design matrix such as :

```
design_matrix <- model.matrix(
  ~ 0 + Celltype_factor2 + Batch ,
  data = cellinfo,
  contrasts.arg = lapply(cellinfo[, sapply(cellinfo, is.factor), drop = FALSE],
                         contrasts, contrasts = FALSE))
```

Was giving me a design matrix that was not full rank so it was making me remove one of the coefficients, which I feel is not appropiate.

Additionally, I kept reading many questions and threads about this and I arrived to the conclusion that batch should be a random effect. Mainly because I do not want to just analyze the differences in expression for these specific batches. I tried to implement the following mixed-effects model using `lme4` package(1.1-34)in R (`R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)`).

```
model <- lmer(gene_expression ~ Celltype_factor2 + (1 | Batch), data=cellinfo)
```

But I am getting the following error  (note: I ran it in a subset of my data. I tried subsetting only cells, subsetting both genes and cells. I checked for NAs, all the levels were also included, etc...):

```
Error in !is.na(v.e) && v.e > 0 : 
  'length = 90000' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

I did not find anybody having this issue. I would appreciate some insight, either model-wise or error-wise.

Comment: Try using `traceback()` to find out what function is throwing this error, then set up debug mode on at least that function so you can see what is in `v.e`  .  It looks vaguely like something is expecting a vector or dataframe but is getting nested lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really ought to have a more informative error message (it does now in the development version), but the problem is that (unlike `lm()`), `lmer` can't handle matrix-valued response variables. Example:

```r
dd <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), batch = factor(rep(1:20, each=50)))
dd$y <- matrix(rnorm(1e4), ncol = 10)
lmer(y ~ x + (1|batch), dd)
```

> Error in !is.na(v.e) && v.e > 0 : 'length = 100' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

The proper way to handle this case is by using `refit`:

```r
ans <- vector("list", length = ncol(dd$y))
ans[[1]] <- lmer(y[,1] ~ x + (1|batch), dd)
for (i in 2:ncol(dd$y)) {
   ans[[i]] <- refit(ans[[1]], newresp = dd$y[,i])
}
```

(The example in `?refit` uses `lapply()`, but I think this might be clearer ...)

Comment: This works nicely Ben! I would not have been able to figure it out myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether `lmer()` is appropriate for your tasks as it fits only linear models. It is unclear how your dependent variable, gene expression, is measured. But I assume that often gene expression is measured

- binary: present or not. Try `glmer(family = binomial())`
- ordinal: none, low, medium, high. Try `ordinal::clmm()` which also works in the binary case and is superior than glmer() for more flexibility.
- count: typically nonnegative integers. Try `glmmTMB(zi = ~, disp = ~ , family = c(poisson(), nbinom1(), nbinom2(), ...))` which also fits fractional numbers, zero inflation, over dispersion, and random effects.
- continuous: positive concentration. Try `glmer(family = gamma())`, as the response cannot take negative values.

While the loop mentioned by Ben works well, you may need to reconsider what happens when fitting 29,733 different models since you can those many genes to assess. If there is no difference between cell types or by the factor of interest, there should be roughly 29,733 * 5% = 1,487 models showing p < .050 and 297 models reporting p < .010. It will be difficult to identify true effects out of all the noise, but false-discovery-rate p-value adjustment should be helpful.

It is okay if you combine cell type and the factor into one categorical variable, but it is also beneficial to separate them so you have both main and interaction effects estimated, as in `lmer(gene_expression ~ celltype * factor2 + (1 | batch), data=cellinfo)`. If factor2 is in fact a continuous variable, you should also check its function form by adding its square, cube, logarithm, or spline smoothers to find the best fit.

If linear models fit the data well, you may want to try the {systemfit} package instead, which runs seemingly unrelated regression where error terms across equations correlate. This technique may suit your needs if multiple genes' expressions are driven by common latent factors (and batch may be one). But allowing 29,733 error terms to correlate with each other, yielding a 29,733 by 29,733 variance matrix of the error terms, sounds crazy and unfeasible. There might be ways to simplify the matrix structure (e.g. compound symmetry by batch number, so it becomes a 20 by 20 variance-covariance to estimate). I am unsure whether such constraints can be done in `systemfit()`. I heard that when the right-hand-side predictors are identical across equations, seemingly unrelated regression reduces to regular regression as if separately estimated. I will need further research to confirm this, but someone else could help. I am not sure whether and how random effects matter here.

You may also want to try factor analysis and use the results to construct structural equation models from the {lavaan} package, where a few common latent factors drive multiple gene expressions. With this, you can have cell type and the effect of interest affect these latent factors. The measurement model part of gene expressions can be linear, binary, or ordinal to my knowledge. It does not yet accommodate other response link functions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Jerry! Very useful. Let me give you some more information about my study: We have `log normalized count data`, and we want to see the differences in gene expression for each cell type within each cell state (which is the other factor of 3 levels). The model would be `gene_expression ~ celltype * factor2 + (1 | batch), data=cellinfo`. We are only interested in the combination of cell type and factor2 and we want to study the contrasts I put in my first comment.

Comment: As you mentioned it is true that for `zero inflated data` one should probably lean towards glmm but I have read a comprehensive benchmark for sc differential expression link and for my data properties they actually suggested `limmatrend` (with or without batch) or `wilcox rank test` (`Seurat`, `FindAllMarkers` function). I am however, trying many different approaches to see the intersectional results.

Comment: Answer updated. With count data, you can use linear models, ordinal regression, and count models. With zero inflation, count models may work better. You don't need to transform the response. A contrast is just a different parametrization, you should not worry about it until after fitting the model. With your 4 by 3 two-way design, you have at most 11 effects (coefficients) to estimate plus one reference (intercept), which is the same as an intercept, a factor of 3 coefficient, a factor of 2 coefficients, plus all their interactions 2 * 3 = 6 terms.

Comment: If you used generalized linear models, effects on the response count is not linear to the coefficients or the predictors (linear predictor), so you should only estimate differences among the contrasts AFTER estimating the model by predicting with new data. You may find package {marginaleffects} useful. I have used it with glmmTMB() models of count data. 

Wilcox test compares distributions, equivalent to ordinal regression with one dummy. 
I am unfamiliar with `limmatrend`. Is it this one? https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks again Jerry. For single cell count data we will most of the times have zero inflated anyways (I wonder why people dont use it much). However in the benchmark I mentioned they say an ordinary linear model (with or without covariate) works best for high sparse (90%), low depth (4) and substantial batch effect. Another point is the intercept, I have had a bit of a headache with this. I do not want any group to be the reference group thats why I had no intercept in my model.

Comment: If I do the model as you suggested with no intercept: `gene_expression ~ 0 + celltype * factor2 + (1 | batch), data=cellinfo` I get that many coefficients are not estimable (all of them from the combination of `celltype * factor2`), which is a problem for me because I really need to have all the coefficients. However, no collinearity happens if we used the combined factor model: `gene_expression ~ 0 + celltype_factor2 + (1 | batch), data=cellinfo`. If we drop the coefficients in the first model we wont be able analyze the contrasts afterwards since we have no coefficients for those

Comment: And answering your question, yes that link is what I meant with limmatrend. I will take a look at your suggested package plus the function suggested.

Comment: You should always include an intercept, thus the errors. Make sure the predictors are factors not fractions. As I mentioned, you can always estimate the desired contrasts after fitting the model. But to fit the model, use the default treatment contrast encoding. Using any other contrast to fit doesn’t offer any advantage. After fitting, you can manipulate predictor values and form linear combinations of estimates response to derive the contrast. Use {marginaleffects} contrast() for this.

Comment: The marginaleffects function is comparisons(). I don’t know what the batch effect characteristics are, but the batch X cell type table looks good to me: no sparsity. The choice of model type can be based on current data fit, so no need to use a method that fits others’ data best.

Comment: I appreciate your insights very much. Actually I tried as you mentioned with intercept and its true that there are no collinealities. The approach required a "less" intuitive contrast matrix afterwards (since two of my levels became the reference) but I believe I managed. Now the objective is to find the correct method that fits my data best. I will play with the package you suggested me!

Comment: Correct, you will by default have both Cell Type A and State 0 as the reference in two factor variables. The reference level choice is arbitrary, does not affect goodness of fit, and loses no information. What you had without intercept is "perfect collinearity" although collinearity in general is not an enemy. No benefits to avoid using any reference levels. As I indicated, you can derive all the 12 desired contrasts after fitting a model then using `marginaleffects::comparisons()`. For more involved statistical tasks, you may find me on LinkedIn and use my data science consulting service.